# Flutter app cannot connect to cloud firestore due to another api used

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'am using a tabbar and first page contains a youtube data api v3, when I navigate to another page containing Cloud Firestore I'am getting an error.

**Error:**

- Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=The project was disabled or deleted., cause=null}
- This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

I have create a new project without youtube api and this time I didn't get any firestore error, the application runned without any problems. So I think there is no problem with the internet connection of the device, the problem is caused by youtube api running.

**Note:** I have add internet permission to AndroidManifest.xml

main.dart codes:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Uygulamam",
      home: TemelOrtam(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Youtube Api codes:

```
class YoutubeState extends State<Youtube> {
  static String anahtar = "***";

  YoutubeAPI _youtubeAPI = YoutubeAPI(anahtar);
  
  static String arama = "Popular Musics";
  static List<YT_API> sonuclar = [];
  static bool sayfaKontrol = true;

  Future apiCagir() async {
    if (sayfaKontrol) {
      sonuclar = await _youtubeAPI.search(arama);
      sonuclar = await _youtubeAPI.nextPage();
      sayfaKontrol = false;
    }
    return sonuclar;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: apiCagir(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) => yerlestir(index, snapshot),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 5,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Cloud Firestore codes:

```
class Arkadaslar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("kisiler")
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      event.docs.forEach((element) {
        print(element.data()["isim"]);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to log in with Google before fetching data from the YouTube API? If yes, are you login with Email and password the YouTube API is not used?

Comment: No, I am trying to fetching data from cloud firestore

Comment: But how are you authenticating the user to fetch the data from Firestore?

Comment: I don't use authentication for now

Comment: Well, you'll have to authenticate the user in order to fetch data from Firestore (or almost any other API for that matter).

Comment: When you create a cloud firestore for the first time in firestore, there are two options. (Start in locked mode and Start in test mode). I chose the start in test mode. So as far as I know no authentication is required. I have tested fetching data from firestore in another project and I didn't get an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error message indicates that something is missing with the basic setup.

```
Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=The project was disabled or deleted., cause=null}
```

Few things to check:

- Is your firebase project correctly setup? Have you added Android/iOS as well?
- Please make sure that you already added `firebase config file` as described in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)?

Comment: I added firebase config file, but I'll try again on a new project

Comment: You were right, there were deficiencies in the setup, thank you